# Add explode array as keys to new array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

```
$input = "hello|world|look|at|this";
$explode = explode("|", $input);
$array = array("Title" => "Hello!", "content" => $explode);
```

This will output:

```
array(2) {
  ["Title"]=>
  string(6) "Hello!"
  ["content"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "hello"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "world"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "look"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "at"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "this"
  }
}
```

But I want them to be keys with a NULL as value as I add values in a later step.

Any idea how to get the `explode()` function to return as keys? Is there a function from [php](/questions/tagged/php) available?

Comment: [array_fill_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) when you're creating the array in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop on the explode to add them:

```
foreach($explode as $key) {
    $array["content"][$key] = "NULL";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_fill_keys` can populate keys based on an array:

```
array_fill_keys ($explode, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about `array_flip($explode)`? That should give you  this

```
array(2) {
 ["Title"]=>
 string(6) "Hello!"
   ["content"]=>
    array(5) {
      [hello]=> 1
```

No `null`values but atleast you got the keys right

Comment: Values wouldn't be null. However you could do something after such as `foreach($new_explode as &$val) { $val = null; }` after.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "hello|world|look|at|this";
$explode = explode('|', $input);
$nulls = array();
foreach($explode as $x){ $nulls[] = null; };
$array = array("Title" => "Hello!", "content" => array_combine($explode, $nulls));
```